# ServicePulse gets hit on security scan

Tags: nservicebus

We are running a Nessus security scan.  Unfortunately Particulars ServicePulse executable is coming up as a hit.

```
Path : c:\program files (x86)\particular software\servicepulse\servicepulse.host.exe
Used by services : Particular.ServicePulse
File write allowed for groups : Everyone
Full control of directory allowed for groups : Everyone
```

I thought it might be because of the service so I disable the service but it still comes up as a hit in the scan.

Is this software needed for NServiceBus if we are not using a dashboard to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the security scan does not like Everyone having full control. As long as the account the service is running under has `Read and execute` permissions it will work. By default ServicePulse is installed to run using the `Local System` account.

There is an issue open to address this https://github.com/Particular/ServicePulse/issues/514

Comment: Thats what I thought too... but then I turned off the service and they ran the scan again and it got hit yet again.... I will give the like you mentioned a try tomorrow and have them run the scan again see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

ServicePulse dashboard gives an [overview](https://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/) of your endpoints and failing messages.

If you are *not* using it to begin with, your endpoints will continue running, but you'll be flying blind as [ServiceControl](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/) will be ingesting any failed messages and you won't see if there are any. If you use [Heartbeat plugin](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/plugins/heartbeat) or any other custom checks, that info will be not visible either.

There's an option of [integrating with ServiceControl events](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts), though I suggest you examine how your environment is set up in regards to ServiceControl, and don't disable ServicePulse without understanding the implications of disabling it and knowing your monitoring is covered.

Comment: Unfortunately its causing a hit with our security scanning software and the powers that be do not want this hit.  We are trapping messages and such via API calls so we are not flying completely blind.

Answer (score 1):

The scan is complaining about file permissions that are too open. Everyone should not have write permissions in any Program Files folder.

I inspected my installation folder and have the same issue.

The fix is relatively easy:

1. Select the properties of folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServicePulse`
2. Select the *Security* tab
3. Select *Advanced*, a new dialog opens

   - Select *Enable inheritance*
   - Select *OK* and *Yes* on any confirmation dialog
4. Select *Advanced* again

   - Check *Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions entries from this object*
   - Select *OK* and *Yes* on any confirmation dialog
5. Select *Advanced* again for the 3rd time

   - Remove the current entries where *Inherited from* states *None*, on my system those were *Everyone* and *System*, make sure that you see all other entries inherited from the parent folder and make sure you do not remove any of them.
   - Select *OK* and *Yes* on any confirmation dialog

It seems like hard procedure but that is because I'm being very detailed here. Some steps potentially can be combined but doing one change at a time keeps things easy to understand.

Now your file permissions are correctly set and comply to your security audit software.

Comment: I have already marked the answer.... there was another before you that was basically the same thing.